# Change nav item color depending on page

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the color of the nav links depending on what page you are on. It is a fixed header. ([Here](http://tinyurl.com/kdgfrwn) is the link to my site).

For example, on the front page it is black and easy to read -

[image]

But when you go to the site's posts the backgrounds are black, making the nav links impossible to read -

[image]

Is it possible to change the nav links based on the post's id?

Comment: Based on post id's might be a bit of a pain in terms of maintenance, you probably want something more flexible. Are all posts going to have a black background?

Comment: @Nick R, yeah, annoyingly

Comment: If all other pages have a black background it would be easier to say If on the Homepage, use black font, otherwise use white font. Wordpress has 'is_home()' for php, and some themes have a body class you might be able to use.

Comment: ^ Yeah, and even easier if you're using Wordpress, as it adds it's own classes to the body tag, like `<body class="home page">` and `<body class="single...` for single blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the body tag class by the post unique slug.

```
<body class="<?php print $post->post_name; ?>">
```

like [here](http://www.katiedev.com/famv1/uncategorized/blackfoot-phoenix/) it will be:

```
<body class="blackfoot-phoenix">
```

and then in the css:

```
.blackfoot-phoenix #cats li a {
    color: white;
}
```

You can also do it with the post id: postid-193 that in the body class.

```
.postid-193 #cats li a {
        color: white;
}
```

You can see the postid if you right click and do "View Page Source".

Comment: Wow, almost.. but whenever I add a class to the body it screws up the page... http://tinyurl.com/nxehooc

Comment: You must add it, not replace the default class.

Comment: Yeah I added it, not replaced

Comment: You also screws the head tag. now the title & scripts tags moved to the body. something wrong there.

Comment: It's a custom page. Here is the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Fh6s/ I just added the body at the top

Comment: The <?php get_header(); ?> needs to be above the body: http://jsfiddle.net/9Fh6s/2/

Comment: Y its a custom page? you don't need to do every post custom page. just add the post name in the body class, and at the css change whatever you want.

Comment: When I place the header before the body it doesn't work.. stupid wordpress..

Comment: You also have the postId in the class of the body: postid-193 so you can do it with it.

Comment: Look at the end of my answers. Just use the postid class in the body. just add the css:        .postid-193 #cats li a {
        color: white;
}

Comment: Nailed it! :) You can see the postid if you right click and do "View Page Source".

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type='text/css'> 
  #black a { color:black }
  #white a { color:white }
</style>
```

...

```
<a id="<?php echo$color;?>" href="" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you would like the outcome to be, you could give it a white background on the header links using css:

```
#cats li a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

By doing this it will appear normal, but on dark background it will have white behind the text. Alternatively you could assign it a class and set it per page using classes. Wordpress is not very friendly setting per page, but there may be some plugins available. Try something like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/stylesheet-per-page/installation/